# Sorting a dictionary and get top 3

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary which stores members of a 'Skiing' tournament. It also stores there scores. What I want to do is be able to find and display the top 3 scores of the members. I was just wondering what the best way would be to approach this as I am stuck at the moment. The following is the dictionary and how a member is added:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Skier> Skiers = new Dictionary<string, Skier>();

    static int income;


    string lodgeName;

    public SkiLodge(string newLodgeName)
    {
        newLodgeName = lodgeName;
        Skiers = new Dictionary<string, Skier>();
    }

    static int newNumber = 1;
    //ADD SKIER
    public Skier AddSkier(string inName, string inAddress, int inScore)
    {
        string newNumberString = newNumber.ToString();
        Skier result = new Skier(newNumberString, inName, inAddress, inScore);
        newNumber = newNumber + 1;
        Skier S = new Skier(newNumberString, inName, inAddress, inScore);
        Skiers.Add(newNumberString, S);
        income = income + 100;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you storing score as strings?

Comment: Do you mean top three scores or rather scores or top three players? In general, players can have same scores. E.g. if you have players with scores 100, 90, 90, 80, top three (distinct) scores are 100, 90, 80, but scores of top three players are 100, 90, 90.

Comment: `string lodgeName;

    public SkiLodge(string newLodgeName)
    {
        newLodgeName = lodgeName;
        // ...
    }` This looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to replicate the behavior and fixed some of the issues in above code. In AddSkier you dont need to create 2 objects.
FetchTopThree() will give you the top 3 results. You can then display the results.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


    public class SkiLodge
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, Skier> Skiers = new Dictionary<string, Skier>();

        static int income;

        string lodgeName;

        public SkiLodge(string newLodgeName)
        {
            this.lodgeName = newLodgeName;
        }

        static int newNumber = 1;
        //ADD SKIER
        public Skier AddSkier(string inName, string inAddress, int inScore)
        {
            string newNumberString = newNumber.ToString();
            newNumber = newNumber + 1;
            Skier skier= new Skier(newNumberString, inName, inAddress, inScore);
            Skiers.Add(newNumberString, skier);
            income = income + 100;
            return skier;
        }

        public List<Skier> FetchTopThree()
        {
            return Skiers.Values.OrderByDescending(s => s.InScore).Take(3).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Skier
    {
        public string NewNumberString { get; }
        public string InName { get; }
        private readonly string inAddress;
        public int InScore { get; }

        public Skier(string newNumberString, string inName, string inAddress, int inScore)
        {
            this.NewNumberString = newNumberString;
            this.InName = inName;
            this.inAddress = inAddress;
            this.InScore = inScore;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I assumed that you have a property in Skier called Score, here how can you achieve your goal.

```
    //Your dictionary must have at least 3 entries.
    var orderedTopThree = Skiers.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value.Score).Take(3);
```

Answer (score 3):

Either of these methods added to your `SkiLodge` class, will get you what you're looking for.

This will grab your top X KeyValuePairs with the `Skier` object being the `Value` property of the `KeyValuePair`.

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string,Skier>> GetTopSkiers(int howMany)
{
    return Skiers.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value.Score).Take(howMany).ToList();
}
```

This will grab your top X Skiers

```
public List<Skier> GetTopSkiers(int howMany)
{
    return Skiers.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value.Score).Take(howMany).Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
}
```

Both methods use the [OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855(v=vs.100).aspx) Linq method, which uses a lambda expression as a selector for the sorting comparison `kvp => kvp.Value.Score`. Which in this case is saying, foreach kvp (`KeyValuePair`) in this dictionary, sort them by the `Value` property, which in this case is the `Skier` object, and use the Skier object's `Score` as the value to sort by.

[Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx) will take, up to x values from an `Enumerable`.

[Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx) then returns an `Enumerable` resulting from the lambda function passed in. In this case, `kvp => kvp.Value` returns an `Enumerable` of `Skier` objects, instead of a list of the `KeyValuePair` objects.

Comment: wonderful BenVlodgi, none of the answers including mine had a provision to cater scenario when one might want to get more or less Top Skiers. Creating generic function with howMany parameter is a master stroke.

Answer (score 1):

You may use LINQ to achieve. Here is one sample query:

```
Skiers.OrderByDescending(e=>e.Value.inScore).Take(3).ToList();
```

Comment: How would I get this to display in a text box?

Comment: This will be a list so Displaying a list to a text box is not looking good. So instead you may display it in a comma separated value to a textbox.

    YourPropertyBindedToTextBox = string.Join(",",Skiers.OrderByDescending(e=>e.Value.inScore).Take(3).ToList());

Answer (score 1):

Either use a SortedDictionary or enumerate through the keys of dictionary or this code

```
   public class Skier
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, Skier> Skiers = new Dictionary<string, Skier>();
        public int inScore { get; set; }
        public Skier()
        {
            int[] highscore = Skiers.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => ((Skier)x.Value).inScore).Take(3).Select(y => ((Skier)y).inScore).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using System.Linq, the following code will get you the best 3 Skiers by score:

```
public List<Skier> GetTop3()
{
var list = Skiers.OrderByDescending(sk=> sk.Value.Score).Take(3).ToList();
return list;
}
```